# A flask/gunicorn service runs fine on physical machine but loose connection in docker even if timeout is set

Tags: docker, rest, flask, gunicorn, connexion

I have a REST service written with [connexion](https://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (a Flask based framework) that I run with gunicorn. The service performs heavy SQL queries to a db and dumps the result in another db. The SQL queries are done in separate threads. When I run my gunicorn command directly on the terminal, the service responds well with a 200 status code after 10minutes. Here is the gunicorn command I am using :

```
gunicorn "src.group.application.my_service.api.app:create_app()" -b 0.0.0.0:8080 --timeout 900 --workers 1 --log-level debug
```

When I use the same command in docker (in the entrypoint.sh file), the service begins to execute like it should. But after 1 minute, the endpoint returns:

```
TypeError: The network connection was lost.
```

the log messages say :

```
[WARNING] Worker with pid 9 was terminated due to signal 9
my_service_1  | [2021-06-02 11:51:53 +0000] [194] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 194
```

and the service is rebooted.

This happens even if I set the `--timeout` flag to a large value. It seems like the value I set to this flag is not taken into account and I have no idea why.

I tried to set the `--graceful-timeout` flag as well with no success. I also tried using async workers such as gthread. I still get the same behaviour.

I reran the Gunicorn commands with `--log-level` set to debug, and could not find differences between gunicorn config inside and outside docker. Here is the gunicorn config in both cases :

**Gunicorn config inside docker**

```
config: ./gunicorn.conf.py
wsgi_app: None
bind: ['0.0.0.0:8080']
backlog: 2048
workers: 1
worker_class: sync
threads: 1
worker_connections: 1000
max_requests: 0
max_requests_jitter: 0
timeout: 900
graceful_timeout: 30
keepalive: 2
limit_request_line: 4094
limit_request_fields: 100
limit_request_field_size: 8190
reload: False
reload_engine: auto
reload_extra_files: []
spew: False
check_config: False
print_config: False
preload_app: False
sendfile: None
reuse_port: False
chdir: /app
daemon: False
raw_env: []
pidfile: None
worker_tmp_dir: None
user: 0
group: 0
umask: 0
initgroups: False
tmp_upload_dir: None
secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
accesslog: None
disable_redirect_access_to_syslog: False
access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
errorlog: -
loglevel: debug
capture_output: False
logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
logconfig: None
logconfig_dict: {}
syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
syslog: False
syslog_prefix: None
syslog_facility: user
enable_stdio_inheritance: False
statsd_host: None
dogstatsd_tags:
statsd_prefix:
proc_name: None
default_proc_name: group.application.my_service.api.app:create_app()
pythonpath: None
paste: None
on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x7fa9a084d940>
on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x7fa9a084da60>
when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x7fa9a084db80>
pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x7fa9a084dca0>
post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x7fa9a084ddc0>
post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x7fa9a084dee0>
worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x7fa9a0862040>
worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x7fa9a0862160>
pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x7fa9a0862280>
pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x7fa9a08623a0>
post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x7fa9a0862430>
child_exit: <function ChildExit.child_exit at 0x7fa9a0862550>
worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x7fa9a0862670>
nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x7fa9a0862790>
on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x7fa9a08628b0>
proxy_protocol: False
proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
keyfile: None
certfile: None
ssl_version: 2
cert_reqs: 0
ca_certs: None
suppress_ragged_eofs: True
do_handshake_on_connect: False
ciphers: None
raw_paste_global_conf: []
strip_header_spaces: False
```

**Gunicorn config inside docker**

```
config: ./gunicorn.conf.py
wsgi_app: None
bind: ['0.0.0.0:8080']
backlog: 2048
workers: 1
worker_class: sync
threads: 1
worker_connections: 1000
max_requests: 0
max_requests_jitter: 0
timeout: 900
graceful_timeout: 30
keepalive: 2
limit_request_line: 4094
limit_request_fields: 100
limit_request_field_size: 8190
reload: False
reload_engine: auto
reload_extra_files: []
spew: False
check_config: False
print_config: False
preload_app: False
sendfile: None
reuse_port: False
chdir: /Users/user/<code_folder>
daemon: False
raw_env: []
pidfile: None
worker_tmp_dir: None
user: 501
group: 20
umask: 0
initgroups: False
tmp_upload_dir: None
secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
accesslog: None
disable_redirect_access_to_syslog: False
access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
errorlog: -
loglevel: debug
capture_output: False
logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
logconfig: None
logconfig_dict: {}
syslog_addr: unix:///var/run/syslog
syslog: False
syslog_prefix: None
syslog_facility: user
enable_stdio_inheritance: False
statsd_host: None
dogstatsd_tags:
statsd_prefix:
proc_name: None
default_proc_name: src.group.application.my_service.api.app:create_app()
pythonpath: None
paste: None
on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x100efd1f0>
on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x100efd310>
when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x100efd430>
pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x100efd550>
post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x100efd670>
post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x100efd790>
worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x100efd8b0>
worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x100efd9d0>
pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x100efdaf0>
pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x100efdc10>
post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x100efdca0>
child_exit: <function ChildExit.child_exit at 0x100efddc0>
worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x100efdee0>
nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x100f06040>
on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x100f06160>
proxy_protocol: False
proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
keyfile: None
certfile: None
ssl_version: 2
cert_reqs: 0
ca_certs: None
suppress_ragged_eofs: True
do_handshake_on_connect: False
ciphers: None
raw_paste_global_conf: []
strip_header_spaces: False
```

What does signal 9 mean ?
How can I make the service inside docker behave the same way than outside docker ?

Comment: Signal 9 is a force-kill, sent by the scheduler. It basically means the scheduler decided the process needed to be kill. This generally is due to resource issues.